# Calculating total hours and date in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I make two activities : one is starting job activity and second is finishing job activity, these two activity get the current time of the system.

Now I want finishing activity get the starting job activity time and subtract the staring job activity current system time from finishing job activity current system time and give the total hours and date?